# Is there a way to remove all eventlisteners outside of a form?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a feature that opens a feedback form after you click a button, but i want to disable all event listeners that are not in inside of the div that contains my form.

This is my code

```js
//Elements that have eventlisteners in this case let's say buttons have .eventlisteners('click', function), i want to disable them all when i open the feedback and enable them again when i close or submit
```

```css
.form-container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="skip-button">example</button>
<button type="button" id="skip-button">example</button>


    <div class="form-container" id="form-container">
        <form id="form">
            <div id="Title-container">
                <p>Please give us feedback!</p>
                <i class="close icon icon-max" id="close-feedback-box"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="area-container">
                Was this app helpful?
                <div class="option-buttons">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="feedback" class="option-button" value="yes">Yes</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="feedback" class="option-button" value="no">No</label>
                </div>
                <div class="submitMessage">
                    <textarea name="feedback-text" id="feedback-message" cols="20" rows="6" placeholder="Please, enter your message..."></textarea>
                    <div class="button-container">
                        <button type="submit" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Instead of that you can make an overlay for your feedback form with a fixed height and width as the window width and height and a fixed position or even absolute, so it covers the whole window and that prevents the user from interacting with other elements outside of your form

Comment: In javascript you can only remove NAMED eventlisteners. However, you can simply set the 'disabled' property of the buttons, they they won't be clickable.

Comment: I know i can use removeEventListeners, but what i was really asking was a way to do it by disabling all child events inside of a div tag

Answer (score 0):

To actually remove all the event listeners, you'd have to loop over every element and call `.removeEventListener()` on each, but you'd have to know what event(s) were being handled and which listener(s) were wired to them, and you can only remove event handlers that have been named (not anonymous or arrow functions set up as handlers).

If you just want to make sure that only your button's event handler is called, you may want to go ahead and set up it's `click` event handler as usual, but then add `event.stopPropagation()` at the end of the handler so that the event doesn't bubble up to any other elements.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log("you clicked outside of the form");
});

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  console.log("you clicked inside the form, but the event didn't bubble up outside of it.");
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
     Click me directly

    <form>
       <button type="button">Click me</button>
    
   </form>
  </div>
</body>
```